# How to sum every two rows into one row with missing data presented and unchanged?

Tags: awk

I have a multi-column file with 2N rows, and it is composed of 0s,1s and missing data(coded as "?"). It looks like this:

```
1 0 0 ? 1 ?
1 ? 1 ? 1 1
1 0 1 ? 1 1
0 ? 0 1 0 ?
0 0 1 ? 0 0
0 0 0 ? 0 ?
0 ? 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to sum up every two rows and output a N row file. If there's a "?" in a row then the output should be "?" for that specific field (?+0=?+1=?+? = ?). So the output from my example will look like this:

```
2 ? 1 ? 2 ?
1 ? 1 ? 1 ?
0 0 1 ? 0 ?
1 ? 1 1 2 2
```

I tried this code, but it seems treating the missing data as "0" while calculating. Is there a way to keep the missing data as "?" ?

```
cat <input_file> |awk -F ' ' '{if (NR%2==1){for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)array[j]=$j;}else{result="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){tmp=array[i]+$i;result=sprintf("%s%d ",result,tmp);}print result;}}' > <output_file>
```

Please help. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Oneliners are cool, but with complicated tasks, whitespace and newlines really help. Especially when trying to understand what the heck is going on. You can use the `-f` option to awk to specify a file with your script.
Probably you'll able to spot the correct location to insert an `if`-statement immediately, where you decide to just `printf` a `?`, or if the two array items need to be added.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you will have to compare each field to `"?"`:

```
< input_file  awk '
NR%2 { split($0,saved,FS) }      # save odd line fields
NR%2 == 0 {                      # on even lines:
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
    $i = $i=="?"       ? "?" :   #  "?" if this line field is "?"
         saved[i]=="?" ? "?" :   #  "?" if the previous line field was "?"
         saved[i]+$i             #  the sum otherwise
  }
  print
}'
```

Comment: +1, but `NR%2 == 0` could be written `!NR%2` ( although here brevity is probably worse ) and UUOC!! ( never a good thing ).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I _knew_ someone would complain about UUOC ;-P

Answer (score 3):

can be done in just a (bash) shell:

```
while read line; do 
    set -- $line
    read line
    ary=( $line )
    i=0
    for arg; do     
        if [ "$arg" = "?" -o "${ary[i]}" = "?" ]; then          
            printf "? "     
        else
            printf "%d " $(( $arg + ${ary[i]} ))     
        fi     
        ((i++)) 
    done 
    printf "\n"
done < file
```

with awk, I'd write something similar

```
awk '{ 
    getline nextline
    split(nextline, ary)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "?" || ary[i] == "?")
            printf("? ")
        else
            printf("%d ", $i + ary[i])
    }
    print ""
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> cat temp.awk
{
if(NR%2==1)
 {
  split($0,a," ");
 }
 else
 {
 line="";
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
 {
  a[i]=="?"||$i=="?" ? sum="?":sum=a[i]+$i;
  line=line" "sum;
 }
 print line; 
 }
}
```

after you create above awk script then use the below command:

```
awk -f temp.awk your_file
```

tested below:

```
> awk -f temp.awk temp
 2 ? 1 ? 2 ?
 1 ? 1 ? 1 ?
 0 0 1 ? 0 ?
 1 ? 1 1 2 2
```